# Is じゃないだろう a negative imperative

Tags: negation, imperatives

So the group of characters receive lunch from one  of the guy's girlfriend, and one of the members of the group says this:

> てめー女にメシばっか作らせてんじゃねーだろうな!

My confusion is, is this an imperative negative? or is it an affirmation about how he always make his girlfriend make lunch?

Answer (score 2):

It's rebuking. It translates to "You're surely not just making women(possibly just "your girl") make food all the time, are you?!"

じゃないだろう translates to "I assume [negate sentence]" and な is a trailing question + exclamation in this case.